# I didn't have "VIRTUALIZATION TECHNOLOGY".Is it possible to run android app without enabling this virtualization technology???

Tags: android, virtualization, haxm

Recently i try to run android app but it ask me to enable VIRTUALIZATION TECHNOLOGY in bios. But my processor is intel pentium T4500 which has no Virtualization Technology facility.Is it possible to run android app without this Virtualization Technology??? Please Help!!! Thanks in advance....

Comment: You need to make your question more clear. What is asking you for VT? Emulator? Have you tried Genymotion?

Comment: You can also run the emulator without Intel HAXM, it will work, but it will just be a lot slower.

Answer (score 1):

For Intel System Image, it's not possible, you will need an Intel processor which supports VT. If you want to run the app without Virtualization Technology, please make sure that you select ARM System Image on AVD, such as armeabi.

From the [official website](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager):

> The Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM) is a hardware-assisted virtualization engine (hypervisor) that uses Intel Virtualization Technology (Intel® VT) to speed up Android app emulation on a host machine. In combination with Android x86 emulator images provided by Intel and the official Android SDK Manager, HAXM allows for faster Android emulation on Intel VT enabled systems.

Note: If your processor is supported, install  Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM) on your PC.

Comment: Is it possible to test on an actual phone connected through cable? PC does not support VT

Comment: @Uzair_07 You only need VT to run the app on emulator. Testing it on physical devices can be done without VT.